# Inductive Specification: Top-down vs Bottom-up vs Rules of Inference?

Tags: math, recursion, logic, theory, induction

Please bear with me on this one. I am first going to describe an example from the book, and then ask my question at the end.

According to the text on Programming Language Paradigms:

> *Inductive specification* is a powerful method of specifying a set of
>   values. To illustrate this method, we use it to describe a certain
>   **subset S of the natural numbers N = {0, 1, 2, . . .}**.

***Top-down definition:***

*A natural number n is in S if and only if*

1. n = 0, or
2. n −3 ∈ S.

We know that 0 ∈ S. Therefore 3 ∈ S, since (3 − 3) = 0 and
0 ∈ S. Similarly 6 ∈ S, since (6−3) = 3 and 3 ∈ S. Continuing in this way, we
can conclude that all multiples of 3 are in S.

What about other natural numbers? Is 1 ∈ S? We know that 1 != 0, so the
first condition is not satisfied. Furthermore, (1−3) = −2, which is not a natural
number and thus is not a member of S. Therefore the second condition
is not satisfied.

***Bottom-up definition:***

*Define the set S to be the smallest set contained in N and satisfying
the following two properties:*

1. 0 ∈ S, and
2. if n ∈ S, then n +3 ∈ S.

A “smallest set” is the one that satisfies properties 1 and 2 and that is a
subset of any other set satisfying properties 1 and 2. It is easy to see that
there can be only one such set: if S1 and S2 both satisfy properties 1 and
2, and both are smallest, then S1 ⊆ S2 (since S1 is smallest), and S2 ⊆ S1
(since S2 is smallest), hence S1 = S2. We need this extra condition, because
otherwise there are many sets that satisfy the remaining two conditions

***Rules of Inference:***

```
_____
0 ∈ S

n ∈ S
---------
(n+3) ∈ S
```

This is simply a shorthand notation for the preceding version of the definition.
Each entry is called a *rule of inference*, or just a rule; the horizontal
line is read as an “if-then.” The part above the line is called the *hypothesis*
or the *antecedent*; the part below the line is called the *conclusion* or the *consequent*.
When there are two or more hypotheses listed, they are connected by
an implicit “and”

---

Now here comes the questions.

- Probably the most important question is why do I need to know these inductive definitions, and how are they useful in the real-world case?
- Why does Google return almost no results on Inductive Definition?
- If top-down, bottom-up and rules of inference essentially display the same thing, why do we need 3 ways of writing the same thing?
- Why is it so hard for me to find the inductive definitions on problems a little more complicated than the book's example, such as the following.

I want to find the top-down, bottom-up, and inferece definitions for the 2 problems below. You don't have to give me the answer, but I do want to know how do I go about deriving the inductive definition. Where do I start? Is there a systematic approach to it (a recipe) for doing these type of problems?

```
1. {2n+3m +1 | n,m ∈ N}
2. {(n, 2n+1) | n ∈ N}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked a lot of questions here, so hopefully this reply answers all of them.  If there's something you'd like clarified, please let me know.

Your first question - why do we need inductive definitions? - is easiest to answer.  In computer science, a huge number of structures are defined inductively.  For example, your simple linked list has the inductive definition

- The empty list is a linked list.
- A single node followed by a linked list is a linked list

Or a binary tree:

- The empty tree is a binary tree.
- A node with two children that are binary trees is a binary tree.

Or regular expressions:

- ∅ is a regular expression.
- ε is a regular expression.
- a is a regular expression for each character a
- If R1 and R2 are regular expressions, R1 | R2 is a regular expression.
- IF R1 and R2 are regular expressions, then R1 R2 is a regular expression.
- If R is a regular expression, R* is a regular expression.
- If R is a regular expression, (R) is a regular expression.

These definitions have many nice properties.  First, they're amenable to recursive algorithms.  If you want to visit every node in a binary tree, we can use the inductive definition of binary trees to build a simple visiting algorithm:

- To visit the empty tree, do nothing.
- To visit a tree formed of a node and two subtrees:

  - Visit the node
  - Visit the left subtree
  - Visit the right subtree

Similarly, if we want to manipulate the structure of a regular expression - perhaps to build a matching automaton for it, for example - then the inductive definition lets us build up automata out of the regular expression piecewise.

Inductive definitions can also be used to formally prove properties of structures.  For example, here's a formal definition of an AVL tree:

- A single node is an AVL tree of order 0
- A node with one or two children that are AVL trees of order 0 is an AVL tree of order 1.
- A node with two children that are AVL trees of order n - 1 or with one child that's an AVL tree of order n - 1 and another that's an AVL tree of order n - 3 is an AVL tree of order n.

Using this definition, it's possible to formally prove that AVL trees are balanced.

We can similarly use these sorts of definitions to prove properties about programming languages.  Most languages have some sort of inductive definition, so by proving that each part of a program preserves some piece of information we can build up correctness proofs from scratch.

Your second question - why doesn't Google turn up any examples for inductive definition? - I think is because it's interpreting it as "define induction," rather than as a term itself.  If you look up *recursive definition*, then you'll find plenty of examples of inductive definitions, as inductive definitions and recursive definitions are very similar to one another.

Your third question - why do we need multiple ways of expressing the same thing? - is also easy.  Inductive definitions are excellent if you want to prove something about a system.  If you prove that it holds for the basic elements, then show that the larger elements preserve that property, you can prove that it's always true.  Recursive definitions are good for writing programs, since recursive functions tend to run induction backwards.  Rules of inference connect with logical proof systems and give a starting point for using classical logic to prove properties of your system.

Your fourth question - why can't you find any examples? - can easily be fixed by taking a minute to look at the classical data structures and algorithms that you know of.  How many data structures could you define inductively?  Try looking at linked lists, binary trees, red-black trees, AVL trees, etc. for inspiration.  How would you define a graph?  A DAG?  Similarly, try looking at syntactic structures.  For example, how would you inductively define strings of balanced parentheses?  How about function prototypes in C?

Your final question - is there a systematic way of solving these problems? - has a negative answer.  You can define recurrences that are equivalent to simulating arbitrary Turing machines on inputs, and since the halting problem is undecidable there is no general procedure for solving these sorts of problems.  Numerous approaches do exist, though.  Try looking at "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik for inspiration about how to work through recurrences.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There is no systematic approach other than "use your brain". 
But you are lucky, because these two example are indeed very close to the original example:

`1`. A natural number k is in S if either a) `k = 1` or b) `k-2 ∈ S` or c) `k-3 ∈ S`

`1`. a) `0 ∈ S` b) `If n ∈ S, then n+2 ∈ S` c) `If n ∈ S, then n+3 ∈ S`

`2`. A pair of natural numbers (k,l) is in S if either a) `k=0 and l=1` or b) `(k-1, l-2) ∈ S`

`2`. a) `(0,0) ∈ S` b) `If (k,l) ∈ S, then (k+1, l+2) ∈ S`

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need to know these inductive definitions, and how are they useful in the real-world case?

The inductive definitions are useful for:

1. Proving properties about members of the set. For e.g. [lambda terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Lambda_terms) can be defined inductively and then you can prove theorems about the terms. You'd use a proof technique called [Structural Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction).
2. Writing functions that manipulate members of the set. We do this all the time in functional programming. For e.g. lists can be defined inductively. That inductive definition is then represented in code using an [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) and then we can write functions on lists as in the `length` function below. Another example is inductive graphs, check out this paper [Inductive Graphs and Functional Graph Algorithms](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/InductiveGraphs_JFP01.pdf).

```
type List a
  = Empty
  | Cons a (List a)

length : List a -> Int
length list =
  case list of
    Empty ->
      0

    Cons _ xs ->
      1 + length xs
```

> Why does Google return almost no results on Inductive Definition?

I don't know but this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1284070409) has a nice chapter (Chapter 3 - Construction Techniques) on it with a ton of examples.

> Why do we need 3 ways of writing the same thing?

Different perspectives gives you different ways to think about the same thing and they can help you to shape your intuition. Read [Developing Your Intuition for Math](https://betterexplained.com/articles/developing-your-intuition-for-math/). In this particular case top-down definitions are good for calculating when an object is a member of the set and bottom-up definitions (rules of inference is just short-hand for a bottom-up definition) are good for generating members of the set.

> Why is it so hard for me to find the inductive definitions on problems a little more complicated than the book's example.

The book I shared above, [Discrete Structures, Logic, and Computability (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1284070409), has tons of examples and exercises, in Chapter 3, for you to understand and practice respectively.

> How do I go about deriving the inductive definition? Where do I start?

Get a feel for the elements in the set. I would first list out some of the elements in the set and see how they can be related to each other. I'd be looking for base elements that can't be defined in terms of simpler elements and then from those base elements I'd be looking to see what rules I could write down to get to the other elements.

Don't look until you've tried for a few hours.

[Answer](https://github.com/dwayne/eopl3/blob/master/03-ch1/ex1.1.md#2) to 1.

[Answer](https://github.com/dwayne/eopl3/blob/master/03-ch1/ex1.1.md#3) to 2.

> Is there a systematic approach?

No. Play with the problem. Come up with ideas and test them out. Read [How to Solve It](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/069116407X) by Polya to develop your problem solving skills.